# how to use create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to use correctly `create` method. Using `create` here I got empty task list after creating a new one. `Pry` told me, undefined method 'create' for nil:NilClass.

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :task, :list, :tasks

  def create
    #task.assign_attributes(task_params)

    #task.save

    task = Task.create(task_params) <--------------------

    redirect_to list_tasks_path(list)
  end

  def update
    task.update task_params

    redirect_to list_tasks_path(list)
  end

  def complete
    task.complete!

    redirect_to list_tasks_path(list)
  end

  def destroy
    task.destroy

    redirect_to list_tasks_path(list)
  end

  private

  delegate :tasks, to: :list, private: true

  def task
    @task ||= params[:id] ? tasks.find(params[:id]) : tasks.new
  end

  def list
    @list ||= List.find params[:list_id]
  end

  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:title, :completed)
  end
end
```

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :list

  def complete!
    self.completed = true
    save
  end

  validates :title, presence: {message: "can't be blank!"}

end
```

Comment: have you create your Task model ?

Comment: Sure. Everything works, when i use assign_attributes and save. But i need to replace this 2 strings with only create method

Comment: Please share your `Task` model.

Comment: Did you `rake db:migrate` ?  You said `Pry` told you.  Which makes me think you're not using browser based testing.  If you were, it might crash and tell you that you have pending migrations.

Comment: of course, I made a migration. The app is working okay when I am using ```assign_attributes``` and ```save```. But I want to replace it using ```create```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help to think that those helper methods are just overly clever. You're also completely lacking any sort of error handling which should not be an afterthought.

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  # see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting
  before_action :set_list, only: [:index, :new, :create]
  before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    # You use new instead of create as it gives you a variable
    # that can be manipulated before you save the record
    @task = @list.tasks.new(task_params)
    # always assume that it can and will fail!
    if @task.save
      redirect_to @task
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    # always assume that it can and will fail!
    if @task.update(task_params)
      redirect_to @task
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def complete
    @task.complete!
    redirect_to list_tasks_path(@list)
  end

  def destroy
    @task.destroy
    redirect_to list_tasks_path(@list)
  end

  private

  def set_task
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_list
    @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
  end

  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:title, :completed)
  end
end
```